# Interpretation and reproduction of auto.arima model selection in R

Tags: r, arima

In RStudio, I run auto.arima on the built-in air passenger data (AirPassengers). The data seems to have multiplicative trend. The forecasting results seem rather accuarte.

[image]

```
# Load the corresponging library.
library(forecast)

# Save the default parameters.
defaultPar <- par(no.readonly = TRUE)

# Prepare a graph of four (2x2) subgraphs
par(mfrow = c(3, 1))

# Fit the model. Use the built in AirPassengers data.
modelAA <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)

plot(AirPassengers, 
     main = 'Air passengers', 
     col = 'purple',
     ylab = 'Passengers number', 
     xlab = 'Year')

plot(forecast(modelAA, 24), 
     main = 'Air passengers + auto.arima forecasting', 
     col = 'red',
     ylab = 'Passengers number', 
     xlab = 'Year')

qqnorm(modelAA$residuals, col = 'red')
qqline(modelAA$residuals, col = 'green')

# Restore the default parameters.
par(defaultPar)
```

As the below code sample suggests, the automated ARIMA forecasting has selected the model(s) as following: (2, 1, 1)(0, 1, 0)[12].

```
print(modelAA)
Series: AirPassengers 
ARIMA(2,1,1)(0,1,0)[12] 

Coefficients:
         ar1     ar2      ma1
      0.5960  0.2143  -0.9819
s.e.  0.0888  0.0880   0.0292

sigma^2 estimated as 132.3:  log likelihood=-504.92
AIC=1017.85   AICc=1018.17   BIC=1029.35
```

How do I interpret the automatic selection (2, 1, 1)(0, 1, 0)[12] and reproduce it by calling arima(x, order = c()...)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a **seasonal arima model**. You can get details from [enter link description here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/67).

[image]

you should set paras `order/sensonal/period` where `period = 12` when you call `arima` `function (x, order = c(0L, 0L, 0L), seasonal = list(order = c(0L, 0L, 0L), period = NA), xreg = NULL, include.mean = TRUE, transform.pars = TRUE, fixed = NULL, init = NULL, method = c("CSS-ML", "ML", "CSS"), n.cond, SSinit = c("Gardner1980", "Rossignol2011"), optim.method = "BFGS", optim.control = list(), kappa = 1e+06)`.

Comment: Seems working. The following function call produced the desired result. modelA <- arima(AirPassengers, order = c(2, 1, 1), seasonal = list(order = c(0, 1, 0), period = 12))